# Is it correct to say imbued in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can I just say 
I am imbued to see this show - such as - I am inspired to see that ?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Something that imbues can do so with qualities or feelings, but not actions.

> The cool weather imbued him with a refreshing feeling.
>
> The color imbued a sad mood to the painting.
>
> The cool weather inspired him to hurry.
>
> The color inspired him to buy a shirt of the same color.

Comment: I would not say "The color imbued a sad mood to the painting" "Imbue" means fill, permeate, influence, soak in, or color or dye, often metaphorically. Soak or moisten is , i think, the original meaning See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imbue and https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/imbue

Comment: @DavidSiegel Your provided definition directly supports the ("often [metaphorical]") use of the word *imbued* in the sentence you question. It makes complete sense to me.